# why I can't stream an audio stored in mega.nz using Android Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

so I can use an exoplayer like this

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("https://mega.nz/file/ZgMhXYKS#WeeFfTd8DEjlD0QjR0XtvPEfEb2kwBQz8wtK7NBQeA0");
```

and play video like sample exoplayer.But i cann't play video.How to solove this.

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer doesn't scrape any website for its direct media Uri like YouTube-DL does for example.
Adding to that, Mega.nz doesn't allow you to get the media Uri, at least not easily, as the content is encrypted, and it's only decrypted when you access their website.